# Renaming multiple columns in different data frames combined into one object

Tags: r, xlsx

I've 65 excel files stored in a folder (i.e. JanuaryFiles). I need to:

1. import every excel file, 2) rename the columns with specific names (all the 65 files should have the same column names), 3) combine the 65 files using any function (e.g., rbind()) into one file, and 4) names it with today's date.

I used:

```
mydir = setwd("~/Dropbox/JanuaryFiles")
myfiles = list.files(path=mydir, pattern="*.xlsx", full.names=TRUE)
myfiles

# Here: I need to rename the columns of each excel file:
# Then I used the following to combine the files:

combined.df <- do.call(cbind , dat_All) 

# I'm also still missing the function that names the final file with specific name and today's date.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lapply` function will read all of your dataframes into a list object called `dfs`. The `col_names` argument is where you provide the names of your columns. `skip` is to ignore the first row, which has the wrong header names (delete this if you want to include the first row of your excel files).

`dplyr::bind_rows` will stack the list of dataframes into one tibble object.

`sprintf("%s.xlsx", Sys.Date())` creates the file name using today's date. You can modify the output format using the `format` function (e.g. `format(Sys.Date(), "%m-%d-%Y"`). Then `xlsx::write.xlsx` outputs the dataframe. Note: it must be a dataframe not a tibble object which is why I used `as.data.frame`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(xlsx)
library(readxl)

# Provide a character vector of column names you want to col_names
dfs <- lapply(myfiles, readxl::read_excel, col_names = cols, skip = 1)
df <- dplyr::bind_rows(dfs)

xlsx::write.xlsx(as.data.frame(df), sprintf("%s.xlsx", Sys.Date()))
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it did not work. It shows this error:

Error: `col_names` must be a logical or character vector                                                                 
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

Comment: `cols` is a made up object here for illustrative purposes. Provide the character vector of column names you want in its place for this to work. For example, `cols <- c("Column1", "Column2")`

Comment: It worked, thanks. The only piece I'm still missing is exporting the final file that includes all 65 files. R shows this message:
```
 xlsx::write_excel(as.data.frame(df), sprintf("%s.xlsx", date())) 
 ```
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.

Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JVM could not be found
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In system("/usr/libexec/java_home", intern = TRUE) :
  running command '/usr/

Comment: Sorry about that, I had the wrong function name. It should be `write.xlsx` not `write_excel`. I've updated the post and it should run now.

Answer (score 1):

You may open the files with `openxlsx::read.xlsx` within an `sapply` loop and set  the column names using `setNames`.

```
col.names <- paste0("V", 1:4)  ## new column names
file.names <- sapply(1:3, function(i) paste0("file", i, ".xlsx"))  ## your file names
library(openxlsx)
r <- do.call(rbind, lapply(file.names, function(x) setNames(read.xlsx(x), col.names)))
r
#   V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1  1  4  7 10
# 2  2  5  8 11
# 3  3  6  9 12
# 4  1  4  7 10
# 5  2  5  8 11
# 6  3  6  9 12
# 7  1  4  7 10
# 8  2  5  8 11
# 9  3  6  9 12
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4))
sapply(1:3, function(i) openxlsx::write.xlsx(dat, paste0("file", i, ".xlsx")))
```